# Reset gridView row selected while paging

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I have a pageView with three tabs, each tab has its own radGridView. Below the pageView I have a form displaying some fields not in the gridView. When the page loads the form gets populated with the first value from the first gridView. But when I change tabs I cannot set the focus to the 'new' gridView. Any tips for getting around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private void radPageView_SelectedPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radPageView1.SelectedPage == radPageView1.Pages["radPageViewPage1"])
    {
        if (this.radGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (this.radGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                this.radGridView1.Rows[0].IsSelected = true;
            }

            this.radGridView2.HideSelection = true;
            this.radGridView2.ClearSelection();
            this.radGridView2.UnSelectAllRows();
            this.radGridView1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            _frmEmbededForm.ResetUI(); //ResetUI is my method
        }
    }
    else if (radPageView1.SelectedPage == radPageView1.Pages["radPageViewPage2"])
    {
        if (this.radGridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (this.radGridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                this.radGridView2.Rows[0].IsSelected = true;
            }

            this.radGridView1.HideSelection = true;
            this.radGridView1.ClearSelection();
            this.radGridView1.UnSelectAllRows();
            this.radGridView2.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            _frmEmbededForm.ResetUI(); //ResetUI is my method
        }
    }
}
```